# JVM backward compatibalitty

Tags: java, jvm, backwards-compatibility

If I have class A that is compiled in Java 1.6
I have class B that is compiled in Java 1.7
In its main method class A invokes a method of class B.

If I run class A under java JVM of version 1.7, everything works well.
May I get an explanation for that?

Comment: The explanation is your title: backward compatibilty. So this is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

All classes compiled under java version 1.6, is supported and runnable by java version 1.6+, including version 1.7, 1.8, etc.

On the other hand, you can't run a program compiled in java 1.7 with a 1.6-JRE.

It's the backward compatibality principle